# Convert utf-8 converted string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with converting a utf-8 decoded string to a list.

```
with open('C:/Users/Nikita/Downloads/bayern_kader.csv','rb') as spielerdatei:
    spielerliste = spielerdatei.read()
    spieler = [spielerliste.decode('utf8')]
    print(spieler)
```

The .csv content:

Joshua Kimmich

Javi Martínez

The result:

```
['\ufeffSpieler\n"Joshua Kimmich"\n"Javi Martínez"\n']
```

What I would like to get:

```
['Joshua Kimmich', 'Javi Martínez']
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might try using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Have you tried spieler.split("\n")?